# Bootstrap Carousel interval alteration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website which uses the bootstrap carousel. Here is my code:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
     <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php
    if ($images = get_field('images', $design_id)) {
    foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        $active = $key == 0 ? 'active' : '';
        echo 'item" data-interval="1000">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image['image']['sizes']['large'] . '" />';
        echo '</div>';                        }
    }
?> 

         </div>
         <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>                                       
         </a>
         <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>                                       
          </a>                                
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 1000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    //Handles the carousel thumbnails
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
            var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });


    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
             var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });

      (function($) {
  fakewaffle.responsiveTabs(['xs', 'sm']);
});

});
```

I changed interval: 5000 to interval: 1000 because there was a delay when the slider would show items when the page loads. Since changing the interval to 1000 the sliders loads perfectly and quickly, however now the slide items need to be slowed down because they more too quickly between slides.

I think the issue is that the "active" state isn't given to a slide/image until after the interval. How can I add an active state to the above code for the 1st slide item automatically on page load rather than waiting until after the interval?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can not use echo inside echo, looks like a php error.

Comment: What about changing it back and using window load instead of document ready: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/ -- you could try it.

Comment: @Christina tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have made any difference

Comment: Would bumping the slide interval back up and then using `$('#myCarousel').carousel('next')` just after page load to manually transition the first slide solve your problem?

Comment: Also, is your jQuery loading in the head or the footer. Why haven't I had this issue? Did you try the data-interval="X" on the html itself, see the docs, and not put it in the js? Are the images really big?

Comment: I just had a thought.. it could be that the slider is loading correctly but for some reason the first slide / image isn't given the "active" class until after the interval @Christina any ideas or suggestions? :-)

Comment: @ClaytonLeis I think the issue could be that the "active" class isn't given to the first slide/image until after the interval - which explains why I thought the slider was taking a while to load..

Comment: You just put .active on the first .item and you don't put it on the others and you also put. active on the first li in the indicators and the data-interval="X" does not go on the item it goes on the .carousel -- see the docs. Actually the docs are not clear on that, but remove it from the item and stick it on the carousel. Remove the js and only use active on the first of both .item and indicator

Comment: @Christina I get that I need to put .active on the first item, but how do you achieve that using the above php code?

Comment: Use jQuery for that part of it. I have the code somewhere. I will look for it and post it when I get back from voting and eating -- 3-4 hours.

Comment: thanks @Christina your a lifesaver :-) being pulling my hair out trying to get it work! :-)

Comment: Here it is: http://jsbin.com/xixuge/1/edit -- change .tweet-slider to your id or class

Comment: Oops: http://jsbin.com/xixuge/1.js

Comment: Also remove the height function.

Comment: Basically see that item:first that's what you need and you need to make another one, just below for the :first of the li using similiar syntax. Give it a shot and when I get back I'll look

Comment: @Christina thanks so much!! thats done the trick :-) had to play around a bit with code but got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used to fix the issue:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
    });

     $('#myCarousel .item:first').addClass('active');
});
```